# Calculate the covariance between $X_s$ and $X_t$

Tags: brownian-motion, stochastic-analysis, covariance

Let $(B_t)_{t \ge 0 }$ be a standard Brownian Motion and let $(X_t)_{t \ge 0}$ be defined by
$$X_t= e^{-t/2}cosh(B_t).$$

For each $s\le t$, calculate the covariance between $X_s$ and $X_t$.

Before getting to this question I showed that $(X_t)_{t \ge 0}$ is a martingale. So, $E[X_s]E[X_t]=1$, right?

Comment: It seems to me like $E[X_s]E[X_t]=1$ (assuming $B_0=0$ and $(X_t)$ is a martingale), since if $(X_t)$ is a martingale, then $E[X_t]=E[X_s]=E[X_0]=1$.

Comment: Yes, you are right. Sorry for the mistake.

Comment: Also, notice that by the tower rule, $E[X_tX_s]=E[E[X_tX_s\mid \mathcal{F}_s]]=E[X_sE[X_t\mid \mathcal{F}_s]]=E[X_sX_s]=E[X_s^2]$ if $s\le t.$

Comment: Ok. So one would get then $$E[{X_s}^2]=e^{-s}cosh(B_s)^2=e^{-s}1/2(cosh(2B_s)+1)=e^{-s}(e^{2s}/2+1/2)$$

Comment: Yes, thats correct!

Comment: Thx a lot for the help!